# AngularJS - radio checked based on object value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

What I'm trying to do is have a service (lets say: myService) that holds specific data like objects representing printers present and selected:

```
var localPrinters = [{ id: 12, name: 'HP', type: 'laser' },
                     { id: 33, name: 'Lexmark', type: 'laser' }];
var activePrinter = {};
```

In some view that gets shown occasionally (like app settings), I have a controller that would define variables in the local scope which would point to the objects in the injected myService.

The view would then use ng-repeat to iterate over printer objects in localPrinters and display radio buttons that correspond to each object in the array..

Now i need two things..
1) update the activePrinter upon radiobutton selection change with the corresponding object value
2) in case the activePrinter already contains an object, when the view loads i want the corresponding radio to be checked already (if its value object matches the object in activePrinter, otherwise none should be selected.

I've managed 1) in a couple of ways.. either sticking to the model usage or adding methods to call upon ng-change.

```
 //pseudocode
 <container ng-repeat="printer in printers" >
      <radio ng-value="printer" ng-model="$scope.activePrinter"/>
 </container>
```

or

```
//pseudocode
 <container ng-repeat="printer in printers" >
      <radio ng-value="printer" ng-change="selectPrinter(printer)" "ng-model="$scope.activePrinter"/>
 </container>
```

What i'm having trouble with is 2)
Not sure if there's a way in angular to automatically figure out some of the printer values matches the activePrinter selection and make the radio checked. Also not sure of the way i'm using ng-model for this purpose.

Any pointers?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked [Angular input radio docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D)?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in this way:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.printers = [{
    id: 12,
    name: 'HP',
    type: 'laser'
  }, {
    id: 33,
    name: 'Lexmark',
    type: 'laser'
  }];

  $scope.activePrinter = {};
  
  //set default printer
  $scope.activePrinter.printer = $scope.printers[0]

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="firstCtrl">

    <div class="container" ng-repeat="printer in printers">
      <label>{{printer.name}}</label>
      <input type="radio" ng-value="printer" ng-model="activePrinter.printer" />
    </div>

    Active Printer:{{activePrinter.printer.id}} | {{activePrinter.printer.name}} | {{activePrinter.printer.type}}

  </div>
</body>
```